# Rotate location of pixels of a color output node?

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes

Is it possible to take the color output of a shader node and rotate the location of pixels?[image]

Comment: You already have the necessary setup.  Go to the Mapping node and do the rotation there.

Comment: right, I put an X there because it requires copying nodes, so if I want to make any changes to said nodes I have to do it twice... oh what about grouping and instancing? In blender, can't you make a group where that group can have multiple instances (and any changes made to one reflects to the rest)?